# Chef::Node available in library called from recipe, but not when called through Singleton Class

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've written a service hub that allows me to stop and start services, a very simplified version of the structure is below without service dependencies added.

```
class Otbo
  class Services (requires Singleton)
    SERVICE_WEBLOGIC = {
      :start => lambda { Otbo::Services.instance._WLStart() },
      :stop => lambda { Otbo::Services.instance._WLStop() }
    }
    module Controller
      def control(service, command)
         service[command].call()
      end
    end
    include Otbo::Services::Controller
    include Singleton
   end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Otbo::Services::Controller)
Chef::Resource.send(:include, Otbo::Services::Controller)
```

In another cookbook library to avoid circular dependency, I have added the include via the send method - which ties up the below `_WLStart()` and `_WLStop()` methods in the lambdas in the code above here.

```
module OtboDomain
  module Util
    def _WLStart()
      if has_role?(node, 'weblogic_adminserver') or has_role?(node, 'otbo_weblogic')
        puts 'Starting WebLogic...'
      end
    end
    def _WLStop()
      if has_role?(node, 'weblogic_adminserver') or has_role?(node, 'otbo_weblogic')
        puts 'Stopping WebLogic...'
      end
    end
  end
end

Otbo::Services.send(:include, OtboDomain::Util)
```

When accessing `_WLStop()` or `_WLStart()` directly from a recipe via an `extend OtboDomain::Util` I am able to access the `node` attribute happily. All good.

When I call through via `Otbo::Service.control(service, command)` method I lose node context and it is not available in `_WLStart()` or `_WLStop()`, so I get an error.

```
node01 ================================================================================
node01 Recipe Compile Error in c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/otbo_weblogic/recipes/default.rb
node01 ================================================================================
node01
node01 NameError
node01 ---------
node01 undefined local variable or method `node' for #<Otbo::Services:0x000000000819d018>
node01
node01 Cookbook Trace:
node01 ---------------
node01   c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/otbo_domain/libraries/util.rb:200:in `_WLStop'
node01   c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/otbo_services/libraries/control.rb:36:in `block in <class:Services>'
node01   c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/otbo_services/libraries/control.rb:74:in `block in control'
node01   c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/otbo_services/libraries/control.rb:69:in `each'
node01   c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/otbo_services/libraries/control.rb:69:in `control'
node01   c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/otbo_weblogic/recipes/setup.rb:114:in `from_file'
node01   c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/otbo_weblogic/recipes/default.rb:12:in `from_file'
```

Is it possible to make the `node` attribute available when calling via `Otbo::Service.control(service, command)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach to create a [custom resource](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html).

```
resource_name :otbo_service
actions [:stop, :start, :restart, :nothing]
default_action :nothing

property :service, Hash, required: true

action_class do
  def control(commands)
    handle(new_resource.service, commands)
  end
end

def handle(service, commands)
  name = service[:name]

  for command in commands
    service[command].call()
  end
end

action :nothing do
  Chef::Log.info('Nothing to do.')
end

action :stop do
  control([:stop])
end

action :start do
  control([:start])
end

action :restart do
  control([:stop, :start])
end
```

I added a library function that can access the node variable.

```
module Common
  module Util
    def _WLStart() 
      Chef::Log.info("<< Starting WebLogic Server on Host: #{node['hostname']} >>")
    end

    def _WLShutdown() 
      Chef::Log.info("<< Stopping WebLogic Server on Host: #{node['hostname']} >>")
    end
  end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Common::Util)
Chef::Resource.send(:include, Common::Util)
```

In the recipe I can then call the custom resource via code something like the following.

```
extend Common::Util

weblogic = {
  :name => 'weblogic',
  :start => lambda { _WLStart() },
  :stop => lambda { _WLShutdown() }
}

otbo_service 'Restart WebLogic' do
  action :restart
  service weblogic
end
```